# How to check the existence of a JToken key in a JSON object string using C#?

Tags: c#, json

Here is json object as follows:

```
string jsonString = "{\"name\":\"John\",\"age\":30,\"city\":\"New York\"}";
```

I need to know whether it existence of `"age"` or not.
Please give me ur hand.
I tried a lot, but I couldn't get I expected.
I have to know whether `"age"` value is existed on `jsonString` or not.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a C# code snippet to check if a key exists in a JSON object string using JSON.NET:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Your JSON object string
        string jsonString = "{\"name\":\"John\",\"age\":30,\"city\":\"New York\"}";

        // Parse the JSON string into a JObject
        JObject jsonObj = JObject.Parse(jsonString);

        // Key to check for existence
        string keyToCheck = "age";

        // Check if the key exists in the JSON object
        bool keyExists = jsonObj.ContainsKey(keyToCheck);

        // Output the result
        if (keyExists)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"The key '{keyToCheck}' exists in the JSON object.");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"The key '{keyToCheck}' does not exist in the JSON object.");
        }
    }
}
```